# How to get a JS function to execute itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have a background image (width = 2000px, height = 400px) sitting behind a div with width and height equal to 400px. My image is split into 5 blocks, all with width and height equal to 400px. I want my image to shift by 400px each time the function is called to emulate a GIF image.

```
    var imageWidth = $("#imageScroll").width();
            console.log(imageWidth);

    var timer = setInterval(function(){ shiftImage() }, 250);

    function shiftImage(){
            $("#imageScroll").mouseover (function(){
                $("#imageScroll").css({"background-position-x": (imageWidth)});
            });
        };
});
```

This is my jQuery code, and I have tried and failed on a lot of different code. imageScroll is the ID of the div that I want the image to be pushed through.

Comment: Your question title seems to have nothing to do with the question body.

Comment: Apologies. Basically, I want to repeat the shiftImage function 5 times so that I can skate through the different images within the larger background-image.

Comment: Isn't this question really: "*I want to make an automatic slide-show*"?

Comment: can you simulate your question in JsFiddle so it' can be easy to follow and try a solution for you?

Comment: Stackoverflow has had a perfectly good Code Snippet feature for live HTML/CSS/Demos for months. There's no need to bump people over to JSFiddle.

Comment: bad idea to add an event listener every time you call `shiftImage`. You should start and stop the timer outside the `shiftImage` function by listening once to `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

Comment: @MohammedElSayed — That isn't how `setInterval` works. The return value of `setInterval` is used to **stop** the interval, not start it.

Comment: @Quentin: sorry, my mistake.  :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to define css of the image so that it repeats itself on the x-axis.

```
<style>
    #imageScroll{
        height: 400px;
        width: 500px;
        background-image: url('./background.jpg');
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
    }
</style>
```

then, at the bottom of the page, or in body onload, you should execute the following instructions.

```
intervalFunc = setInterval(shiftImage, 250);

function shiftImage(){
    var currentBackgroundX = $('#imageScroll').css('background-position-x');
    split = currentBackgroundX.split("%");
    currentBackgroundX = split[0];
    currentBackgroundX = parseInt(currentBackgroundX);
    $('#imageScroll').css({"background-position-x": (currentBackgroundX + 25) + '%'});
}
```

I didn't give too much though about the positioning part actually, since that is a completely different subject. But what i'm trying to do here is, change the background-position-x by 25% every 250 miliseconds. You can change the inner workings of the shiftImage function.

If you want to stop the animation at any point, just run

```
clearInterval(intervalFunc);
```

Hope this helps

Edit: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2t9nzgaf/5/)

Edit 2: edited fiddle link

Edit 3: edited fiddle link

Comment: That works great, but I want to stop it when it gets back round to the original image? How do I do that?

Comment: let's say that you want to animate when mouse enters the div, you just use $('#imageScroll').hover(startAnimate, stopAnimate); I'll be editing the fiddle shortly

Comment: check out the new fiddle